# CSV импорт товаров по разделам

Tags: php, битрикс

Доброго времени суток! Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.

Как правильно настроить импорт товаров по разделам по полю CODE?

Поясню: у меня есть csv файл с товарами, и там есть три свойства: рубрика первого уровня, рубрика второго уровня и рубрика третьего уровня. Соответственно, у меня есть большое количество разделов, которые я импортировал через веб-сервис и записал в базу. Там у каждого раздела есть стринговый идентификатор, который я решил записывать в поле CODE. И когда при импорте я указываю соотношение полей - ничего не происходит. В смысле импорт происходит, но товары не идут в разделы. Надеюсь, понятно объяснил.

Можете подсказать, как настроить импорт через поле CODE. Может, что-то неправильно делаю. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Если кому поможет - настроить импорт разделов через админку битрикса у меня не вышло. Но можно организовать импорт вручную. Сначала берем список с разделами и их свойствами, это может быть csv, excel, веб-сервис и т.д. В этом массиве каждый раздел добавляем с помощью `CIBlolckSection::add()`. После того как добавили все разделы, делаем импорт всех товаров через админку. И чтобы все товары добавить в разделы, пользуемся `CiBlockElement::SetElementSection()`. На самом деле так даже удобнее получается, так как можно организовать автоматический импорт.